# Are there any non-evil Faerûnian deities that are against dragons?

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms, religions-and-deities, dragons

I want to create a character who is dragon slayer. And I kinda want a deity to worship and use as "assistance" when killing dragons.

So is there any deity that is against dragons and also within good or neutral alignment in the Forgotten Realms?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Bahamut

Bahamut is the explicit rival of all Evil Dragons in the realm, as they are the servants of Tiamat.

> [Bahamut began preparing for the resurrection of the Dragonfall War as Tiamat had regained her status as lesser deity thirteen years prior](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Bahamut)

[Hell, he's even recruiting.](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Rite_of_Rebirth)

Answer (score 5):

Giants are traditional enemies and rivals of dragons, and spent a thousand years fighting them.  The [giant pantheon](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Giant_pantheon) would be keen to strike down hostile dragons, and keep other dragons in their place.  One possible patron might be [Hiatea](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Hiatea), goddess of hunting.  (Shhh!  I'm hunting dwagons!)

It's unusual, but not unknown, for 'small folk' to worship giant deities.  Whether a smaller humanoid would get much aid in exchange is a matter of celestial politics.